# iOS Swift: Displaying asynchronous data on a TableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, uiviewcontroller

I have a `ViewController` with a `TableView` in it, now the data for `TableView` is pulled via an http call asynchronously in another class.

```
class ViewController1: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
            self.tableView.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")

            MyHttpClass().getData()//INITIATING getting data asynchronously
...
}
```

`MyHttpClass` gets the data after a few seconds asynchronously, but it does not have a reference of the `ViewController` to hand over the data (ideally the ViewController.tableView.reloadData - is what i need to call)

Is there a better way to handle this? How do i get ref. to `ViewController` instance when `MyHttp` gets the data? Any better way to handle this?

Answer (score 3):

Well, I suggest you to use call back,add a input as this

```
 func getData(callBack:()->()){
    //When finished
    callBack()
}
```

Then call

```
MyHttpClass().getData() { () -> () in
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

The best way to solve this problem would be to make `MyHttpClass().getData()` take a callback to execute when it finishes loading the data asynchronously.  In this callback you can then reload the tableview.